# Finding Differences between two dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes and here is a sample. My actual file has over 600 rows.

```
Bay = c(1,1,2,3,4,5)
Row = c(1,1,2,3,1,1)
Facings = c(1,2,1,3,1,1)
Product = c("Wipes", "Scented Wipes", "Bleach", "Cleaner", "Dish Soap", "Plunger")
FirstAisle = data.frame(Bay,Row,Facings,Product)
Product = c("Scented Wipes", "Bleach", "Dish Soap", "Wipes", "Cleaner", "Plunger", "Drainer")
Row = c(1,2,2,1,1,1,2)
Bay = c(1,2,2,1,1,5,1)
Facings = c(1,2,1,1,1,2,1)
SecondAisle = data.frame(Bay,Row,Facings,Product)
```

The product names will be the same for both, but they might be in different order. In the second aisle they might also be moved to a different row, or bay. They might also have a different number of facings on the second aisle. I am trying to figure out a way to determine which products have moved to different areas, and whether the number of facings for the product has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nm = colnames(FirstAisle)
data.frame(lapply(nm, function(x){
    if(is.numeric(FirstAisle[[x]]) & is.numeric(SecondAisle[[x]])){
        FirstAisle[x] - SecondAisle[x]
    }else{
        data.frame(FirstAisle = FirstAisle[[x]],
                   SecondAisle = SecondAisle[[x]])
    }
}))
#  Bay Row Facings    FirstAisle   SecondAisle
#1   0   0       0         Wipes Scented Wipes
#2  -1  -1       0 Scented Wipes        Bleach
#3   0   0       0        Bleach     Dish Soap
#4   2   2       2       Cleaner         Wipes
#5   3   0       0     Dish Soap       Cleaner
#6   0   0      -1       Plunger       Plunger
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the awesome code. Do you know if there is a way to do this without having the same number of rows between both data sets?

Comment: Editted. I added a new row in SecondAisle that does not exist in FirstAisle. Thank you for your time